# Add a driver to phone for win7 machine to detect

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, usb-drivers

recently bought a Vodafone Smart Ultra 6, tried to connect it to my machine (Win7 64-bit pro) and it came up with "USB Driver not found".

Now, here's why this is an issue:

1. I have internet on my phone but not on my desktop
2. the only way to get that file because of point 1) would mean having to transfer the driver to my pc from my phone.. which I cant because there is no driver!

is there a way I can unzip the driver to a certain folder on my phone that Windows will see? Or will it be a long & tedious case of copying the images by hand onto the desktop in the drivers folder?

Thanks,

Comment: Turn ON the mobile hotspot and connect your laptop to that network.

Comment: My desktop doesnt have a wireless reciever, if I dont have wifi why pay a bit more for a reciever... I hate past me haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this without, at minimum, writing custom code for the USB interface on your device.  Devices that present drivers this way do so through a standardized interface that uses generic drivers (that the system will already have), often appearing to be a CD-ROM.  If you can't see something like this or an existing storage location on your phone, you're out of luck.

Comment: awesome just what I wanted haha that's fine I guess I can copy the code into files in the driver folder, a tedious task but a necessary one. Thanks :)